# jQuery - create an element with 16:9 aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, window, divide

I am actually working on an image gallery which contains thumbnails of some videos I made. For this, I calculate the with of the gallery through the following code.

```
$(function() {
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(this).width() - 200;
    $("#gallery").css("width", width);
}).resize();});
```

Now each image should have an 16:9 aspect ratio. Therefore, I have to divide the width of the gallery width 16 and multiply this value with 9. Doesn't seem to be that hard but actually I am stuck. Hopefully someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: `height = width * (9 / 16);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: That's an *answer*, not a *comment*. ;-)

Comment: If you set only one dimension (height or width) on an image, the other dimension will be calculated automatically to match the image shape.  You don't have to set both.

Comment: @jfriend00: That's not my experience. *Edit* ...but a quick experiment suggests it's true! Using script: http://jsbin.com/uCeBuQ/4 Using old-fashioned `width` and `height` attrs: http://jsbin.com/uCeBuQ/2 Using CSS: http://jsbin.com/uCeBuQ/3

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to be honest I'm not sure what element the OP even needs to apply it to, so I'll leave it there :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Setting only on dimension works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/knLqa/

Comment: @jfriend00 That's operating under the assumption that `#gallery` is an image element, which may not be the case.

Comment: @Terry - The OP says "each image should have a 16:9 aspect ratio".  My suggestion is to set the `.width` property of each image and then you don't have to set `.height`.  The browser will maintain the aspect ratio for you.  It's a shortcut that takes advantage of something the browser will do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should recalculate the element height:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(this).width() - 200;
        $("#gallery").css({
            "width": width,
            "height": width*(9/16)
        });
    }).resize();
});
```

Here's a proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/w555h/6/

Comment: This will be a floating point height (e.g. decimal number).  Is that really what you want.

Comment: The browser will handle floating point height by converting that into an integer anyway. Browsers have differences in how quickly they render integers or floating point values, but it's not significant http://jsperf.com/float-css-props

Comment: @Terry: I'm not at all sure I believe that measuring how long it takes the browser to set the `className` relates to how much time it spent on the fractional CSS values, especially not when they're specified in a static `style` element. (That's my +1 on the answer [not the comment], though. [Actually it's quite interesting someone should upvote the comment and not the answer!])

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Now you've gotten me in a tizzy... let me recheck that example I cited :P

Comment: @Terry: To really test this, you'd have to test browser reflow. I'm quite sure browsers are smart enough to handle fractional values quickly enough for our purposes. :-) E.g., I don't buy the test case, but I do buy that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(this).width() - 200;
var ratio = 16 / 9.0;
    $("#gallery").css("width", width).css("height", Math.round(width * ratio));
}).resize();});
```