# Make CSS tabs pop up on hover without pushing the rest of the page down

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tabs

I'm working on developing a design I created that has menu tabs that pop up when you are on the active page or when you hover on them.

It looks like this in my design:

[image]

When it come to development, I've tried playing around with margins and padding, but each of them just push the rest of the site down.

Here is a Jfiddle if you'd prefer to use that. http://jsfiddle.net/CW3f7/

HTML

```
<div class="menu-main-navigation-container">
<ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="nav-menu"><a href="http://www.dorkinggreatwall.co.uk/">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-menu"><a href="http://www.dorkinggreatwall.co.uk/?page_id=7">Contact</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-menu"><a href="http://www.dorkinggreatwall.co.uk/?page_id=9">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav-menu li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
background: #d71921;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.nav-menu li a {
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 1;
padding: 15px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
background-color: #d71921;
color: #fff;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

ul.nav-menu, div.nav-menu > ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 40px 0 0;
}
```

Any code would be greatly appreciated. All of my Google searches bring up unrelated results.

Comment: Please replicate your issue with a Fiddle... and not link to an external site.

Comment: Can you please add to the discussion next time and not just complain? You're as bad as Esmi from the wordpress forums.

Comment: I can't add to the discussion because you are linking to an external site, which may lose context. It is your own perogative how you want to format your question — but having your code on a standalone fiddle or even in the question itself would help us a lot in solving your question. We aren't here to copy and paste code that you have posted elsewhere, period. It's people like you with a horrible self-entitled attitude (who thinks we are complaining, not helping) that really ruins the SO experience.

Comment: Hey! I'm fine with you having to enforce your rules. But I literally just posted that link and there's no reason you can't take a look at it! You've got over 3000 point and yet you can't stoop low enough to answer a simple positioning question? It's people like you that are ruining the SO experience.

Comment: If you'd go through my answer history, you'd see that I help people regardless of how many points they have. In short, you are angry simply because I pointed out that linking to external site will not be helpful to future users, and asked you to port it over to a Fiddle. You're barking up the wrong tree, dude.

Comment: Oh snap, this guy has 5 points and I helped him more than I did for you. Why? Because he played by the rules (posted code in his original question). As simple as that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747690/jquery-create-an-element-with-169-aspect-ratio/19747698

Comment: Terry, I did what you said. I'm just complaining because of the self-righteous attitude you did it in. If followed the rules, I'm just fighting back because I think you were rude.

Comment: I am really dying to know which part of "Please replicate your issue with a Fiddle... and not link to an external site. " is rude.

Comment: I was obviously someone in need, and time is of the essence, and you wanted me to recreate my problem in a completely separate website that I have no control over how long the code will stay up for all while I have a perfectly good working prototype already built. And it's one I control. What i don't get is why you're so stuck to the rules to have to reinforce them before even looking at how amazing my working prototype is!

Comment: Well, JSFiddle is going to stay up there for quite awhile, I can assure you. Therefore, first argument invalid.

Everyone comes to SO in search for help, for an answer to their question. You are no different from a person with no rep points, or a person with 20k rep points, asking a question.

Why is it so hard to recreate your problem? I don't understand at all. If you cannot be bothered to simplify it for us (we are volunteers helping others based on good will, not paid, for goodness sake), then don't complain when someone tries to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Alright. That's more than fair enough. Sorry for taking your advice in a bad way. I did create the Jfiddle once you said. I just wanted to fight against it. But I'll accept you're right. Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

were you thinking something along the lines of this:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heYgb/3/)

```
.menu-item {
    height: 55px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.menu-item:hover, .current-menu-item {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: That's the one! Thanks Lastonehere. I would change your answer from 0 to 1 but I don't have enough reputation. I'll have to buy you a beer instead.

Comment: I believe he has removed the external CSS file it was using, I shall add some basic styles now.

Answer (score 1):

You can add vertical margin for inactive elements, and remove it for active element.

Alternatively you can use absolute position to exclude menu from document flow. Menu size will not impact rest of document.

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain which pieces of CSS code I should put where.

Answer (score 0):

you could set the z-index to 1 or greater, z-index will place it above the other layer
z-index 0 is default most of your website is probably on that. z-index 1 should display it on top

think of it like x, y, z coordinates

Comment: The issue is not the z axis. The issue is the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using positions. Here http://jsfiddle.net/AdrianSis/TU97j/1/ is a fiddle for your case.

```
<body>
<ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

CSS

```
ul.nav-menu{
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 40px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #D71921;
}
ul.nav-menu li{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D71921;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
}
.nav-menu li.active, .nav-menu li:hover{
    top: 0;
}
.nav-menu li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```